# Coordinated changes with java

Tags: java, transactions, java-8

The following a demo sample

```
if (someList.contains(fooObject)) {
  someList.add(someObject);
  someStorage.serialize(someObject);
}
```

I need to perform two coordinated tasks: adding an object `someObject` to `someList` and serialize it to storage `someStorage`. I would like `someList` and `someStorage` had a consistent data: both operations succeeded or if some of them failed, or rolled back if one succeeded, but other failed. How it can be done?

Comment: Well, what does "storage" mean?  db, file, network?

Comment: For now it an xml file.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is taking a 2-phase commit(-ish) approach. So you restructure the addition and serialization operations such that you perform all intermediate operations that may fail initially. Then store the intermediate result in a variable. After you've validated both intermediate results were generated, commit the changes.

Something along these lines

```
if (someList.contains(fooObject)) {
  boolean r1 = someList.preAdd(someObject);
  boolean r2 = someStorage.preSerialize(someObject);
  if ( r1 && r2 ) {
    someList.commit();
    someStorage.commit();
  } else {
    if (!r1) someList.rollback()
    if (!r2) someStorage.rollback()
  }
}
```

Depending on the actual interface, you may want to use `try/catch` rather than `if/else`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (someList.contains(fooObject)) {
  // we start with the operation which is easier to undo
  try{
    someList.add(someObject);
    //the first operation is succeded
    try{
      someStorage.serialize(someObject);
    }catch(Exception ex){
      // the second operation faild --> undo the first
      someList.remove(someObject);
      //report error
    }
  }catch(Exception ex){
    // the first operation faild -->   report error
  }  
}
```